# Localization of Django model float field in forms

Tags: django, localization, floating-point, django-forms

I'm trying to localize a model float field in django forms.

This way it's working:

```
super(....)
self.fields["field_name"] = forms.FloatField(localize=True)
```

However I don't want to define a new form field, instead I would like to add the localization to my existing model field. This way it isn't working:

```
super(....)
self.fields['field_name'].localize = True
```

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong with my approach?

Thanks, 
Jonas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the form field does various bits of initialization when it is instantiated, and setting the `localize` attribute after that does not rerun that initialization. See [the code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/fields.py#L102).

You might be able to get most of what you want by additionally setting the `is_localized` attribute on the widget:

```
self.fields['field_name'].localize = True
self.fields['field_name'].widget.is_localized = True
```

but at this point you'd probably be better off re-declaring the field anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, unfortunately it's not working in my case, so I'm going with the second way. Are there different approaches though getting this result?

Answer (score 1):

My approach was:

*settings.py*

```
DECIMAL_SEPARATOR = ','
USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = True
```

Form's *__init__* function

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(YourForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['field'].localize = True
    self.fields['field'].widget.is_localized = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Django provides a way to tell explicitly which fields should be localized.
You just add 'localized_fields' to your Meta Model class.

```
class FormEditBuilding(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Building
    exclude = []
    localized_fields = ['apartments_sqm', 'offices_sqm']
```

Django-Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#enabling-localization-of-fields

Thanks to @heyhugo

Comment: Found in docs here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#enabling-localization-of-fields